# No wireless capabilities on menu bar after fresh 16.04 LTS install

Tags: networking, 16.04

I'm very new to Ubuntu again, I haven't touched it since Desktop 13, and I will need some hand-holding here.
I can't connect to a network. I've been frustrated trying to find a solution to here and I've mashed more code through terminal than I'd like to admit. Would anyone be willing to help me solve this? I will do my best to answer any questions I can.

Comment: Please provide details about your wifi adapter.

Comment: Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4356 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

Comment: Type ifconfig in your terminal and post your results. Also, tell us what is actually going wrong. Is your WiFi adapter not listed, is it not working at all, or is it detecting networks but not connecting?

Comment: `enp60s0  Link encap: Ethernet HWaddr ac:9e:17:3e:d0:85`      I'm not sure that my card is working. I have tried enabling proprietary software in Updates but it never responds by using the driver.

Comment: I'll take all the help I can get. I want to become proficient in Ubuntu and this will be the first step: getting connected to the internet.

Comment: I tried to run the code
`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`
and the reply it gave me was:
`Media change: please insert the disk labeled 'Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)' in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter]`

Comment: You need an alternative internet connection to install software from the repositories. Just plug in an Ethernet cable and it should install the restricted driver automatically.